# How to write text files with sys.args[] as part of the filename?

Tags: python, pandas, filenames

I am pretty new to Python and I am trying to filter some rows in a dataframe based on whether they contain strings or not. I want the script to automatically use the input name to save the filtered dataframe on a text file.

Suppose I read my file with `python3 code.py input.txt` and my code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
import sys

data = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], sep='\t', header=0)
selectedcols = data['Func.refGene']
selectedrows = selectedcols.str.contains("exonic|splicing")
selecteddata = data[selectedrows]
selecteddata.to_csv(f'{sys.argv[1][:-4]}_exonic.splicing.txt', index=None, sep='\t', mode = 'a')
```

Where 'Func.refGene' is the column I want to search through for the strings "exonic" and "splicing". I have written this code and it worked before, but now I try to run it and the following error occurs:

```
File "code.py", line 12
    selecteddata.to_csv(f'{sys.argv[1][:-4]}_exonic.splicing.txt', index=None, sep='\t', mode = 'a')
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Would anyone know what could be wrong? I have searched for this syntax and haven't had any success.

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.2

Comment: f-string is available from python 3.6 onwards that's why you are facing the issue. use `format`

Comment: thank you so much! these multiple servers will make me insane one day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for below python 3.6,

```
selecteddata.to_csv('{0}_exonic.splicing.txt'.format(sys.argv[1][:-4]), index=None, sep='\t', mode = 'a')
```

f-string supports from python 3.6 https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals